# Talkback is not working in android with react-native-pdf

Tags: android, react-native, pdf, react-native-pdf

I have tried integrating react-native-pdf to load pdf from url in react-native. It loads the pdf in both iOS and android. But I want accessibility also to work in both platforms. In iOS voiceover reads the content but in android it doesn't even go to the pdf and found similar issues posted by many.

I would like to know if there is any way to achieve talk back to work in android pdf with this or any other library. Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.